# setTimeout - заставить делать остановку

Tags: jquery

Есть у меня фоновая картинка, прорисованная 13-ю слайдами, мне нужно их плавно прокрутить, чтобы была видимость анимации. Делаю как ниже описал, однако setTimeout не приостанавливает выполнение ни на долю секунды, и все проходит мгновенно, что пользователь видит статическую картинку. (Через отладчик, всё круто, изображение с каждым проходом меняется, нужно только его задержать не на долго.)

И еще один непонятный эффект, после того как if становиться не актуален. Выполняется отдельно setTimeout несколько рас, почему я так и не понял.

```
function shake_box(posY){
  if( posY > -7000 ) {
    posY = posY - 600;
    jQuery('#cookieBusket').css({'background-position': '0px ' + posY + 'px'});
    setTimeout(shake_box(posY), 1500);
  }
}

jQuery("#cookieBusket").click(function(){
  shake_box(0);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Меняем

```
setTimeout(shake_box(posY), 1500);
```

на

```
setTimeout(function(){shake_box(posY)}, 1500);
```

смотрим результат :)

Comment: Дай бог вам здоровья. Спасибо, всё заработало как нужно :)